# Is it possible to use a variable changing its name in loop as input for a function in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My intention is to read multiple files and record the data in the corresponding array.
The array will be further processed then.
example:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5
do
    set -A data$i
done

i=2
t=data$i

//read data from file into data2, data3 ...
read_file(){

ifile="/tmp/proc/test/2"   //should loop all files in the folder, file 2, 3, 4, ..., save to data2, data3, ....
j=1
for i in $( awk  -F ',' '{ print $1; }' "${ifile}" )
do
    t[$j]=$i
    echo "${t[$j]}" 
    j=$((j+1))
done
    echo "done read_file"
}

//intention to process data2, data3..., but not sure how to do it.
process_data(){
input=$1
  
#echo ${!$1}
 
#for line in "${!input[@]}"
#do
    #echo "test: "
    #eval "echo \$$line"
    #echo ${!line}
        
#done
#}

#process $t

}
```

Is it possible to do this with shell script (bash is ok as well)?
Are there other ways to do it?
Please kindly give suggestions.
Thanks.

A little update about my target: I want to read files in a folder, mark all duplicates and count the occurrence of duplicates across files. Then for each file in the folder, give a summary of how many unique items, how many duplicate items and the times of the occurrence of the duplicates.(duplicates should only occur between files)

My original script reads all files in the folder, use awk to get all duplicates and occurrences (save to file of all_dup), then compare each file to all_dup (use awk), give each_file_dup, each_file_uniq.

I'm thinking to speed it up by writing data into array instead of files.
But not sure if it actually works.
The files vary from hundreds to thousands of lines (long int).
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Dynamic variable names are possible (see [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)), but generally messy and easy to get wrong. I'd recommend trying to restructure your code so they're not needed.

Comment: yes, I am thinking about it, but not pop out any good ideas yet. Thanks.

Comment: Could this be an [XY Prolem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Please expand on the *details* of "get all duplicates". You mean dups within a file? Or across files? If you can write CLEAR specifications, I'm sure we can come up with something fast and comparatively simple, or at least clean. :)

Comment: Duplicates should only occur between files. Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd be better off writing this in something other than bash; something with decent data structures. My preference would be Python, but there are plenty of good options. Shell scripts are good for telling other programs to do complex things with data, but bad at actually working directly with complex and/or large data sets.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I totally agree. @Gordon

Answer (score 2):

Reading several files into *one* array is trivial.

```
arrayName=( $( cat file1 file2 $someGlob ) )
```

If the file names are also valid as array names you can use dynamic evaluation.

```
$: grep . ?
a:1
a:2
a:3
b:4
b:5
b:6
c:7
c:8
c:9

$: lst=(?)
$: set -x; for f in ${lst[@]}; do eval "$f=(\$(<$f))"; eval : "$f: \${${f}[@]}"; done; set +x
+ for f in ${lst[@]}
+ eval 'a=($(<a))'
++ a=($(<a))
+ eval : 'a: ${a[@]}'
++ : a: 1 2 3
+ for f in ${lst[@]}
+ eval 'b=($(<b))'
++ b=($(<b))
+ eval : 'b: ${b[@]}'
++ : b: 4 5 6
+ for f in ${lst[@]}
+ eval 'c=($(<c))'
++ c=($(<c))
+ eval : 'c: ${c[@]}'
++ : c: 7 8 9
```

Personally, I prefer a sourced temp file.

```
$: for f in ${lst[@]}; do echo "$f=(\$(<$f))">tmpfile; . tmpfile; done;
$: echo ${b[1]} 
5
```

If the files are all have variable-valid names in `/tmp/proc/test/`, then you might use something like this -

```
flist=( /tmp/proc/test/* )
for f in "${flist[@]}"
do echo "${f//[/]/_}=(\$(<$f))" >| tmpfile; 
  . tmpfile; 
done
```

This will use the name `_tmp_proc_test_2` the array for the file `/tmp/proc/test/2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'll definitely think to redesign. I previously used temp file to save data as well, but it turns to be slow, so I think maybe use variable to speed it up.

Comment: It depends what you are doing with the data. Can you back up and explain what you are trying to *accomplish* rather than the problem you are seeing with your attempted new method?

Comment: I updated a bit about my target, please see above. Thanks.